# I want to hide a popup based on the client id and using html5 local storage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm quite new to all of these but here us my problem
I have a popup that has a "don't show this again" checkbox. When a user checks this, local storage should save the client id (which is in the db) and the checked status of the checkbox. Based on these two factor the popup should be displayed or hidden

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#beforelight').css('display', 'block');

    $PopUp = $('#beforelight');

    var hide = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('hide'));
    var id = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('[[clientdb.id]]'));

    if (hide, id) {
        $PopUp.hide();
    } else {
        // initialize value in case it hasn't been set already
        localStorage.setItem('hide', false);
    }

    $('#checkbox').click(function () {
        $('#beforelight').hide();
        // toggle the boolean by negating its value
        var id = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('[[clientdb.id]]'));
        var hide = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('hide'));
        localStorage.setItem('hide', !hide);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Joan and welcome to SO. Can you be more specific about what exactly the issue is. Are there any errors showing in the console related to your code?

Answer (score 0):

#### Please try this code - JSON.parse is returns string

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#beforelight').css('display', 'block');

    $PopUp = $('#beforelight');

    var hide = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('hide')) === 'true';
    var id = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('[[clientdb.id]]'));

    if (hide && id) {
        $PopUp.hide();
    } else {
        // initialize value in case it hasn't been set already
        localStorage.setItem('hide', 'false');
    }

    $('#checkbox').click(function () {
        $('#beforelight').hide();
        // toggle the boolean by negating its value
        var id = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('[[clientdb.id]]'));
        var hide = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('hide')) === 'true';
        localStorage.setItem('hide', !hide ? 'true' : 'false');
    });
});
```

Comment: This is working by adding showing that the checkbox is checked but the popup disappears and reappears almost immediately

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#beforelight').css('display', 'block');
    $PopUp = $('#beforelight');
    var checkbox_status = JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('checked'));
    var saved_id = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('id'));
    window.onload = function(){
    if(checkbox_status="true" && saved_id == stored_id){
      $("#beforelight").hide();
    }
    else if(checkbox_status="false"){
      $("#beforelight").hide();
    }
  };



    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            $('#beforelight' ).hide();
            var checked = true;
        }
        else if($(this).is(":not(:checked)")){
            var checked = false;
        }
        JSON.parse(localStorage.setItem('checked', checked))
        // JSON.parse(localStorage.setItem(saved_id+'checked',checked))

    });
      var stored_id = document.getElementById("client_id").innerHTML;
      JSON.stringify(localStorage.setItem('id', stored_id));
  
});
```